# What does "counting the operations depends on how a function is implemented" actually mean?

Tags: performance

I've been studying algorithm efficiency, and one part of a course said that counting the number of operations (as opposed to timing the algorithm) depends on how a function is implemented (which is written as a downside), and it also depends on the algorithm (which is written as an upside).

What exactly does this mean? What does it mean for two pieces of code to be two different implementations of the same algorithm (am I missing some subtlety here, or does it just mean that two functions that do the same thing but vary slightly in their syntax, count as two separate implementations of the same algorithm)? How is the fact that it depends on the algorithm good, but the fact that it depends on implementations bad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither are correct, the truth lies somewhere in the middle.  The algorithm isnt anything, maybe 30+ years ago, but today a compiler can deconstruct your algorithm and reconstruct it differently (if it has been programmed to recognize what you are trying to do).

Mathmatically: you have probably heard the one in elementary school about adding all the numbers from 1 to 100 up, makes it easier from 0 to 100, so that is either 99 or 100 addition operations yes?  Plus a loop which is a counter and a compare.  Well what if you were to realize that 0+100 = 100, 99+1 = 100, 98+2 = 100.  There are 50 pairs that add up to 100, and then 50 is left by itself.  so we could reduce the 100 additions and a loop with 100 additions and a compare down to 50*100+50 or 50*101.  One multiplication.  You could probably make an algorithm with some constraints perhaps but add up all the numbers from 0 to N with N being positive as the constraint, even vs odd values of N would produce a different generic algorithm perhaps, perhaps not, probably has a N/2 in there and some multiply and maybe an add.  Far cheaper than doing N additions in a loop which the loop variable has to do that many additions and compares.

But what about implementation:

```
00000000 <fun1>:
   0:   e59f0000    ldr r0, [pc]    ; 8 <fun1+0x8>
   4:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
   8:   000013ba            ; <UNDEFINED> instruction: 0x000013ba

0000000c <fun2>:
   c:   e59f0000    ldr r0, [pc]    ; 14 <fun2+0x8>
  10:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
  14:   000013ba            ; <UNDEFINED> instruction: 0x000013ba

00000018 <fun3>:
  18:   e59f0000    ldr r0, [pc]    ; 20 <fun3+0x8>
  1c:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
  20:   d783574e    strle   r5, [r3, lr, asr #14]
```

algorithm was irrelevant in this case, note the compiler even reduced the pseudo random summation loop into the answer.

```
unsigned int fun1 ( unsigned int x )
{
    return(x*10);
}
unsigned int fun2 ( unsigned int x )
{

    return((x<<3)+(x<<1));
}
unsigned int fun3 ( unsigned int x )
{
    return(((x<<2)+x)<<1);
}
```

I was hoping for a multiply but of course didnt get one, maybe I needed to specify the cpu.

```
00000000 <fun1>:
   0:   e0800100    add r0, r0, r0, lsl #2
   4:   e1a00080    lsl r0, r0, #1
   8:   e12fff1e    bx  lr

0000000c <fun2>:
   c:   e1a03080    lsl r3, r0, #1
  10:   e0830180    add r0, r3, r0, lsl #3
  14:   e12fff1e    bx  lr

00000018 <fun3>:
  18:   e0800100    add r0, r0, r0, lsl #2
  1c:   e1a00080    lsl r0, r0, #1
  20:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
```

It didnt need to recognize fun2 and the others are the same.  I have seen the mips backend actually call another midway, so fun3 would branch to address 0 in this case for example, which is more costly than just running the instructions, didnt do it for me on this one, so perhaps I need a more complicated function.

now assuming x is an even number

```
unsigned int fun1 ( unsigned int x )
{
    unsigned int ra;
    unsigned int rb;
    rb=0;
    for(ra=0;ra<=x;ra++) rb+=ra;
    return(rb);
}

unsigned int fun2 ( unsigned int x )
{
    return((x/2)*(x+1));
}
```

we should get a different result, the compiler is not that smart...

```
00000000 <fun1>:
   0:   e3a02000    mov r2, #0
   4:   e1a03002    mov r3, r2
   8:   e0822003    add r2, r2, r3
   c:   e2833001    add r3, r3, #1
  10:   e1500003    cmp r0, r3
  14:   2afffffb    bcs 8 <fun1+0x8>
  18:   e1a00002    mov r0, r2
  1c:   e12fff1e    bx  lr

00000020 <fun2>:
  20:   e1a030a0    lsr r3, r0, #1
  24:   e2802001    add r2, r0, #1
  28:   e0000293    mul r0, r3, r2
  2c:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
```

we assume the multiply is cheap, docs will say one clock but that is not necessarily true, there is a pipe they can save a ton of chip real estate by consuming more and burying the time in the pipe, or as you see in a non-pipelined processor the clocks for a multiply are longer.  we can assume here it is buried in the pipe and if you could keep the pipe moving smoothly it is really fast.

Anyway, we can safely assume with the last example the loop of additions is much slower than the optimized algorithm.  So algorithm as well as implementation help us here.

```
unsigned int fun1 ( unsigned int x )
{
    return(x/10);
}

00000000 <fun1>:
   0:   e59f3008    ldr r3, [pc, #8]    ; 10 <fun1+0x10>
   4:   e0821390    umull   r1, r2, r0, r3
   8:   e1a001a2    lsr r0, r2, #3
   c:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
  10:   cccccccd    stclgt  12, cr12, [r12], {205}  ; 0xcd
```

this is a fun one I can/have shown that the multiply by 1/5th or 1/10th solution is slower than a straight divide if your processor has the divide, there is the additional load there is the shift as well as the multiply, where the divide might be a load and divide.  You have to have the memory be slow such that the extra load and the extra fetch swallow the difference, here again divides are slower that multiplies in general.  but the compiler is still right most of the time the multiply is faster so this solution is okay.  But it didnt implement the operation we asked for directly, so the algorithm changed from the desired to something else.  Implementation saved the algorithm and or at least didnt hurt it.

Look up FFT, this is a classic example of starting with the elementary algorithm that has some amount of math, you can count the operations, then various ways to re-arrange the data/operations to reduce that math, and further reduce it.  And that is great, in that case you are quite likely helping the compiler.  But implementation could help further if you let it and specifically how you write your code can take a great algorithm and make it worse.

```
unsigned int fun1 ( unsigned int x )
{
    return(x*10.0);
}

00000000 <fun1>:
   0:   ee070a90    vmov    s15, r0
   4:   ed9f6b05    vldr    d6, [pc, #20]   ; 20 <fun1+0x20>
   8:   eeb87b67    vcvt.f64.u32    d7, s15
   c:   ee277b06    vmul.f64    d7, d7, d6
  10:   eefc7bc7    vcvt.u32.f64    s15, d7
  14:   ee170a90    vmov    r0, s15
  18:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
  1c:   e1a00000    nop         ; (mov r0, r0)
  20:   00000000    andeq   r0, r0, r0
  24:   40240000    eormi   r0, r4, r0

unsigned int fun1 ( unsigned int x )
{
    return(x*10.0F);
}

00000000 <fun1>:
   0:   ee070a90    vmov    s15, r0
   4:   ed9f7a04    vldr    s14, [pc, #16]  ; 1c <fun1+0x1c>
   8:   eef87a67    vcvt.f32.u32    s15, s15
   c:   ee677a87    vmul.f32    s15, s15, s14
  10:   eefc7ae7    vcvt.u32.f32    s15, s15
  14:   ee170a90    vmov    r0, s15
  18:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
  1c:   41200000            ; <UNDEFINED> instruction: 0x41200000
```

subtle, needed a 32 bit constant vs 64, the math is single vs double, take a more complicated algorithm that will add up.  And in the end could we have just done a fixed point multiply and gotten the same result?

```
unsigned int fun1 ( unsigned int x )
{
    return((((x<<1)*20)+1)>>1);
}

00000000 <fun1>:
   0:   e0800100    add r0, r0, r0, lsl #2
   4:   e1a00180    lsl r0, r0, #3
   8:   e1a000a0    lsr r0, r0, #1
   c:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
```

Would there have been any rounding anyway with x being an integer?

There is no fact either way, it is not a fact that implementation does not matter (even in a classroom with one small chalkboard vs several wide ones, or a whiteboard that the marker lasts longer and erases just as easy) it is not a fact that algorithm does not matter, it is not a fact that programming language does not matter, it is not a fact that compiler doesnt matter it is not a fact that compiler options does not matter it is not a fact that processor does not matter.

timing your algorithms execution is not the end all, be all, I can easily demonstrate that the same machine code runs slower or faster on the same processor and system without doing things like changing clock speed, etc.
Not uncommon for the method of timing the algorithm to add error into the result.  Want to make it fast of one system, time, tweak, time, tweak.  tweaking at times involves trying different algorithms.  for a family of similar systems the same deal but understand where the performance gains came from and adjust based on how those factors vary across the family of targets.

algorithm matters is a fact. implementation matters is a fact.

Note there is no reason to get into an argument with your professor, I would call that a fact, get through the class, pass it, and move on.  Pick your battles just like you would with your boss or co-workers in the real world.  But, unlike the real world you finish the semester you are done with that class and perhaps professor forever, real world you may have those coworkers and boss for a long time and one bad battle or one lost battle can affect you for a long time.  Even if you are right.

Comment: remember cost to maintain harder to read algorithms or heavily hand optimized code is a factor, performance isnt the only thing

Answer (score 1):

Can't speak for what the course authors meant, but perhaps I can clear your second issue.

An algorithm is a description of the actions needed in order to achieve a certain goal / computation. It's given in the language of mathematics most often. Computer programs are one way of implementing an algorithm[1], and the most common. Even if they are quite abstract things, they're still way more concrete than the mathematical description. They're tied to the programming language and environment they are written in and it's various quirks, the specifics of the problem you're trying to solve[2], and even the particular engineer who is writing it. So it's natural that two programs or parts of programs which implement a certain algorithm to be different, and even have different performance properties. The number of instructions executed for a certain input would definitely fall into the bucket of properties which vary between two implementations, thusly.

---

[1] Another way might be in hardware, like a digital circuit or an analog computer, or through some mechanical process, like a clock or one of those mechanical automatons from the 19th century, or even some biological or chemical process.
[2] To clarify, a general purpose sorting routine might be written in a different way than a 16-bit integer sorting routine, even if both of them implement QuickSort.